# Inheriting a WPF control and thread-safety on its member attributes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I had to define the following class in order to enable an automatic scrolling-down when new text is added to a `TextBox`. Moreover, I needed to override the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` methods in order to disable the automatic scrolling-down when the user click on the scrollers.

```
public class ScrollingTextBox : TextBox
{
    private volatile bool _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = true;

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (_AutomaticScrollingEnabled)
        {
            Focus();
            CaretIndex = Text.Length;
            ScrollToEnd();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        object original = e.OriginalSource;

        if (!original.GetType().Equals(typeof(ScrollViewer)))
        {
            if (FindVisualParent<ScrollBar>(original as DependencyObject) != null)
            {
                _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = false;
                Trace.WriteLine("scroll bar is clicked down");
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        object original = e.OriginalSource;

        if (!original.GetType().Equals(typeof(ScrollViewer)))
        {
            if (FindVisualParent<ScrollBar>(original as DependencyObject) != null)
            {
                _AutomaticScrollingEnabled = true;
                Trace.WriteLine("scroll bar is clicked up");
            }
        }
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Only the following methods use the `_AutomaticScrollingEnabled` member attribute:

- the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` method set this attribute to `false` in order to disable the automatic scrolling-down of text box;
- the `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` method set this attribute to `true` in order to enable the automatic scrolling-down of text box;
- the `OnTextChanged` method read this attribute in order to see if the text box should or not to scroll automatically.

How about the thread-safety of the `_AutomaticScrollingEnabled` member attribute? Is it correct to declare this attribute as `volatile`? If, instead of this simple boolean attribute, there was an complex object, would I have to make a lock?

Comment: I don't think volatile or a lock will even be necessary. the UI thread will be handling these events

Comment: Where are you expecting to have multiple threads? All of these events are raised on the UI thread. In general, UI controls are not safe to access from multiple threads.